# How to draw a square using Matplotlib PolyCollection?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to understand `PolyCollection` from Matplotlib by trying a very minimal example to plot a square (I know there are already patches/artists for that) but I would like to understand how should I specify the vertices for `PolyCollection`.

I have tried the following:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
import numpy as np

verts = [[0.0,0.0],[1.0,0.0],[1.0,1.0],[0.0,1.0]]
verts = np.array(verts)
print(verts.shape)

poly = PolyCollection(verts, facecolors = 'blue', edgecolors='k', linewidth=1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim(-1.5, 1.5)
ax.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)

ax.add_collection(poly)

plt.show()
```

but I get the following error:

```
main.py 9 <module>
poly = PolyCollection(verts, facecolors = 'blue', edgecolors='k', linewidth=1)

collections.py 1189 __init__
self.set_verts(verts, closed)

collections.py 1234 set_verts
self._paths.append(mpath.Path(xy, closed=True))

path.py 130 __init__
_api.check_shape((None, 2), vertices=vertices)

__init__.py 164 check_shape
raise ValueError(

ValueError:
'vertices' must be 2D with shape (M, 2). Your input has shape (3,).
```

My vertices have already the shape `(4,2)`.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`verts` should be a list of 2D array-like sequences.

```
PolyCollection?

Init signature: PolyCollection(verts, sizes=None, closed=True, **kwargs)
Docstring:      Base class for collections that have an array of sizes.
Init docstring:
Parameters
----------
verts : list of array-like
    The sequence of polygons [*verts0*, *verts1*, ...] where each
    element *verts_i* defines the vertices of polygon *i* as a 2D
    array-like of shape (M, 2).
```

Since you are plotting just one square, you can write:

```py
square_verts = [[0.0,0.0],[1.0,0.0],[1.0,1.0],[0.0,1.0]]
poly = PolyCollection([square_verts], facecolors = 'blue', edgecolors='k', linewidth=1)
```

Comment: The key is in the name: it's a collection of polygons, not just one.

Comment: @blarg this is the way to go. Also works with more than one polygon.